# Как в переменной после аргумента r поставить другую переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, shutil

В 14 строчке моего кода (4 строчка в функции setup) после "r" ставится строка, мне нужно, что бы после "r" была переменная, но с переменной, а не со строкой "r" не работает, но мне нужно, что бы была переменная. Надеюсь вопрос понятен. Заранее спасибо)

```py
import os, shutil
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('650x400')
window.title('Install mod, by GTA Mania')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.iconbitmap('files\\icon.ico')

def setup():
    entyInfo = str(entry1.get()) + '\foo\bar'

    folder_from = r'iles'
    folder_to = r'E:\end\foo\bar'

    for f in os.listdir(folder_from):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, f))
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
            os.system(f'rd /S /Q {folder_to}\\{f}')
            shutil.copytree(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, f))    

photo = PhotoImage(file="files\\fon.png")
one = Label(window, image=photo)
one.image = photo  # just keeping a reference
one.grid()

textEnter = Label(window, text='''Укажите путь к корневой папке с игрой GTA SA''', fg='black')
textEnter.config(font=('Times', 13))
textEnter.place(x=6, y=340)

butSetup = Button(window, text='Установить мод')
butSetup.config(width=15, height=1, fg='black', bg='gainsboro', font=('Times', 11), command=setup)
butSetup.place(x=255, y=368)

entry1 = Entry(window, width=40)
entry1.place(x=6, y=373)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы `folder_to` была равна `entryInfo` ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов Не ставьте r :)

Comment: Ошибка будет :)

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\end\x0coo\x08ar\\gta3.img'

Comment: @n1tr0xs как исправить?)

Answer (score 0):

Замените объявление переменной `entyInfo` на это: `entyInfo = entry1.get()+ r'\foo\bar'` и в `folder_to` тогда просто передайте ее. Или сразу напишите так:

```
def setup():
    folder_from = r'iles'
    folder_to = entry1.get()+ r'\foo\bar'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Спасли меня прям :)

Comment: Только у вас, я так понимаю опечатка в folder_from. Вы наверняка хотели написать folder_from = r'files'

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов отметьте ответ, пжл, чтобы вопрос можно было считать закрытым.